# Is there way to see widget area location hint in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

In Magento, there is way to enable hint so that we know which block is placed in which location (See example below).

[image: Magento Hing]

I wonder is there any way in Wordpress so that we know the location of widget fronted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

wordpress doesn't have such funcitonality to show the location of widgets.Wordpress has sidebars in which you can put widgets.

you need to go to the appearance -> widget

and find the name of sidebar that it used in your homepage.Likely most of name of sidebar are recognizable for eg : homepage sidebar ,main sidebar,front-page sidebar from where you can add/remove widgets.